# Questions for Algorithm pseudocode of greedy problem

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I've been solving algorithm problems but couldn't solve this question.
It doesn't matter if it is any programming language, I would love to see your approach.

Problem:
Say there are two arrays A, B, which is the time when A and B open the door.
A always opens door, and B always close door, and want to compute how long that door was opened.

For example, A = [3,5,7], B = [4, 10, 12] the output should be 6hrs as A opened door at 3, and remained open until 4, and B closes door, and at 5, A opens door and comes back at 7 but door is remained open, and at 10, B comes back and 10 and closes door.

Can you write pseudocode, or using any programming language to solve?

thank you in advance

Can you write pseudocode, or using any programming language to solve?

Comment: What if A and B have the same value? Will the door then be open or closed? What if the final value in B is less than the final value in A? What should the output be then?

Comment: @trincot they cannot have the same values

Comment: OK, and what if the greatest value in A is greater than any value in B -- so the door remains open at the end -- then how will you count the time the door is open?

Comment: @trincot oopss sorry, the constraints that they provided is that A cannot have the maximum timeframe.

Comment: OK, did you have time to check the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm could go like this:

- Sort both arrays if they are not yet guaranteed to be sorted
- Have two index variables for iterating both arrays, so you have the notion of a "current" value in A and one in B
- Repeat as long as necessary:

  - If the current value in A is not greater than the current value in B:

    - add their difference to the result
    - find the next value in A that is greater than the current value in B and make it the current one
  - Take the next value from B as current

Some boundary cases can occur. Notably when the greatest value in A is greater than the greatest value in B, this means the door will remain open at the end of the procedure, and so you would have an unlimited number of hours that the door is open. You could return "Infinity" in that case.

Here is an interactive implementation in JavaScript. Just alter the input to get a real-time update:

```js
function openHours(a, b) {
    // Make sure both arrays are sorted
    a.sort((x, y) => x - y);
    b.sort((x, y) => x - y);
    // Boundary case: when door is never opened
    if (a.length == 0) return 0;
    // Boundary case: when door remains open for ever
    if (b.length == 0 || a.at(-1) > b.at(-1)) return Infinity;
    let i = 0;
    let time = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
            time += b[j] - a[i];
            // Opening the door is irrelevant until after door is closed
            while (i < a.length && a[i] <= b[j]) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return time;
}

// I/O handling
const [inputA, inputB, output] = document.querySelectorAll("input, span");
document.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    const a = inputA.value.match(/\d+/g)?.map(Number) ?? [];
    const b = inputB.value.match(/\d+/g)?.map(Number) ?? [];
    const result = openHours(a, b);
    output.textContent = result;
}
refresh();
```

```html
A: <input value="3 5 7"><br>
B: <input value="4 10 12"><br>
Result: <span></span>
```